# inserting cookies in my WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-7

The Older post that I've made 30 minuts ago has seen all its responses deleted.. First of all I want to apologize for my English to all the moderator that have corrected me each time I wrote something on this forum :).

Ok so basicaly the problem is that I need to add a token in my WebBrowser Cookies for a bank-app done mostly with webviews.
I've written a test web page that displays the cookies. and I try to hit it like so:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string testCookies = "http://devlbpaccescomptewp7.clicmobile.com/test-read-cookie.html?timeStamp=";
            testCookies += DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie", "lol");
            Uri test = new Uri(testCookies, UriKind.Absolute);
            CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
            cc.Add(test,cookie);

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(testCookies);
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            req.CookieContainer = cc;

            //HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.get
            req.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), req); 

            uriList = new List<Uri>();

           // wB.Navigate(test);
           // wB.Navigate(new Uri(home, UriKind.Absolute));
           wB.Navigating += new EventHandler<NavigatingEventArgs>(wB_Navigating);
        }

        private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
            HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult);

            using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => wB.NavigateToString(results));


            }
            myResponse.Close();
        }
```

I got an UnauthorizedAccessExeption on the wb.NavigateToString line.

Does somebody has already seen that ?

Thanks,
Renaud

EDIT : I corrected the conserned line to make it work !

Comment: Use the Dispatcher to call NavigateToString

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your callback is on a different thread, you need to use the Dispatcher to modify the UI.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => wb.NavigateToString(results));
```

Comment: oh ok, I thought that the callback was on the UIthread. thx very much guys, it works like a charm now !